# Beautiful soup - variable number of sub-tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've set up the following function to extract data from a page, using BeautifulSoup. Which is working nicely, except that on some occasions, there is a `span` tag (with a class element) below the `next_tag` property that I'm passing to the function, so that when I call `contents[0]` I'm not getting far enough down the tree to the real contents that I need.

Here is a page I'm scraping and the elements that are failing start "Expression of interest ".

https://www.londontenders.org/procontract/supplier.nsf/frm_opportunity?openForm&opp_id=OPP-HIS-DNWC-8LBMQ8&contract_id=CONTRACT-DNWC-8LBM3B&org_id=ORG-DNWB-74MCW7&from=%20eoi_start:

I've tried .string instead of contents[0] but it doesn't seem to work with `findNext`.

```
def get_contents (tender_soup, tag, text, next_tag):
    if tender_soup.find(tag,text=text) == None:
        item_name = ''
        return item_name
    else:
        if len(tender_soup.find(tag,text=text).findNext(next_tag).contents) == 0:
            item_name = ''
            return item_name
        else:
            item_name = tender_soup.find(tag,text=text).findNext(next_tag).contents[0]
            item_name = item_name.encode('utf-8')
        return item_name
    return item_name
```

Comment: Please provide an HTML code (or link to) to demonstrate the problem. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.londontenders.org/procontract/supplier.nsf/frm_opportunity?openForm&opp_id=OPP-HIS-DNWC-8LBMQ8&contract_id=CONTRACT-DNWC-8LBM3B&org_id=ORG-DNWB-74MCW7&from=%20eoi_start:

Comment: Thank you, please also show how do you invoke `get_contents()` function.

Comment: `eoi_start = get_contents(tender_soup, "label","Expression of interest start date:","dd");` and `eoi_end = get_contents(tender_soup, "label","Expression of interest end date:","dd");`

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with an egregious hack to get it working, any advice about how to work the tree in a more efficient way would be much appreciated. I've added another function to deal with this data type and added an `if` statement to handle tags with a `len()` of more than 1. I call the function with both potential tags, and filter the commands down according to the the len count of the tag as follows:

```
def get_estimates (tender_soup, tag, text, next_tag, alt_tag):
if tender_soup.find(tag,text=text) == None:
    item_name = ''
    return item_name
else:
    if len(tender_soup.find(tag,text=text).findNext(next_tag).contents) == 0:
        item_name = ''
        return item_name
    else:
        if len(tender_soup.find(tag,text=text).findNext(next_tag)) > 1:
            item_name = tender_soup.find(tag,text=text).findNext(alt_tag).contents[0]
        else:
            item_name = tender_soup.find(tag,text=text).findNext(next_tag).contents[0]

    item_name = item_name.encode('utf-8')        
    item_name = item_name.strip()
    return item_name
return item_name
```